# How much of the environment do I feasibly need to destroy in Darksiders 1?

Tags: darksiders

I just started playing Darksiders 1, and in The Crossroads (the area where you first meet Vulgrim), I found a secret chest by

> destroying all of the fire hydrants.

Now I'm in The Choking Grounds (graveyard on the way to Tiamat), and there are destructible gravestones EVERYWHERE. Will I need to destroy everything in this game to feasibly find all of the hidden chests? I don't want to have to make a point of simply hitting every single thing I see if I don't have to.

Comment: You're on to something with the gravestones, btw. For the rest, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer:

Not really, there are three secret chests in total that require you do destroy/interact with certain object to appear. But later in the game you get *Hoardseeker* and *Fury's Embrace* that reveal the location of the chests on the map, so you can just safely leave the environment intact until the map says there is a chest that you can't seem to find.

## Long answer:

There are three secret chests:

1. The Crossroads

   - Location

     > Main Plaza
   - Interaction

     > Break all six fire hydrants
2. Choking Grounds

   - Location

     > Graveyard
   - Interaction

     > Destroy all the big grave stones
3. Twilight Cathedral

   - Location

     > Basement
   - Interaction

     > Light all the torches

([source](http://darksiders.wikia.com/wiki/Chest))

## Bonus info:

There is a chest in Drowned Pass, but it is quest specific, so don't waste time searching for anything to break like I did. I don't remember what it was, it's a long time ago, but either it is a glitch and there is no chest ([source](http://There%20is%20a%20chest%20on%20the%20map%20in%20the%20northern%20house%20in%20the%20lake%20which%20is%20not%20there.%20Presumably%20this%20is%20a%20caused%20by%20a%20mistake%20when%20the%20map%20was%20created,%20in%20which%20they%20added%20two%20chests%20to%20the%20map%20while%20only%20one%20chest%20was%20created%20in%20the%20game.)) or you can only do it while you are doing the quest

> for the rock door guy and you have to go into those 4 orange portals to get the door clear.

If you don't get it then, you can never get it, but it's only a chest of souls so it doesn't matter.([source](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/how-to-get-chest-in-drowned-pass-darksiders.188440955/))

Comment: Perfect, exactly the information I was looking for. Looks like I'll be able to keep my sanity. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Vaindil No problem, I've been there before and spend hours searching forums and whatnotelse